# Is possible to change the style of a specific value in a p?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a p with a text which changes when clicking on buttons, each button shows a different text depending on the value of a var, I want one of these text to have a different font-size.

```
var language = " "; /* this var changes when another function fires, don't mind this, just know that the var changes and the possible values are 1,2,3 */

function changeText(text1, text2, text3) {
  if (language == 1) {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text1;
  } else if (language == 2) {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text2;
  } else if (language == 3) {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text3;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Don't think about this";
  }
}
/*yeah, I should be more DRY and not repeat document.getElementById('text') all over*/

button.addEventListener('click', () => changeText('whales', 'snails', 'this is the specific text that needs a different font-size'));
button2.addEventListener('click', () => changeText('bees', 'trees', 'this text3 is ok with the actual font-size'));
```

```css
#text {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<p id='text'> dinamic text is in here </p>
```

I want that specific text3 to have a different font-size not all the text3. I modified the function changeText so when language == 3 the font-size of #text is different, but of course this applies to all text3. Hope I was clear, thanks for any help.

I checked similar questions, but if I do:

```
else if (language == 3) {
 document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text3;
 document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = 10px;
```

it changes the font-size of all text3.

Comment: Sure, because styles are applied to the node.  Not to text nodes.  If you only want part of a line of text to be styled, then encapsulate it in a span and style the span

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking -- I assume you only have one element with the ID `#text`? Only that element will receive the style of `text3`, and only when `language` is equal to `3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are changing the innerHTML (opposed to innerText) you could add html tags with the text. E.g.:

**JS**

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => changeText('whales', 'snails', '<small>this is the specific text that needs a different font-size</small>'));
button2.addEventListener('click', () => changeText('bees', 'trees', 'this text3 is ok with the actual font-size'));
```

**CSS**

```
#text>small {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Since you are calling the same function on clicking the different buttons they will have the same behavior. So if you want to do this programatically you will need to add a new function or overcomplicate the already bulky function with weird logic.

The real question that pops up is: Why do you want this behavior?

Comment: thank you, I was exaclty asking if there's a way to do that without writing a new function that would overcomplicate everything. The reason I want that is because a text is waaaay to long compared to the others texts in p and it messes up the impagination.

Comment: If the length of the text is an issue, you may want to see if your design allows a more flexible solution where longer text would fit without problems. Or you could count the length of the string and resize if it's too long. That assumes the characters are the same size across all languages however, which might not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var text = document.getElementById('text');

    function changeText(text1, text2, text3, button) {

      // default behaviour
      text.style.color = "red";
      if (language == 1) text.innerHTML = text1;
          else if (language == 2) text.innerHTML = text2;
          else if (language == 3){ 
              text.innerHTML = text3;
              // different behaviour
              if(button == "button1")
                  text.style.color = "green";
          }
      else text.innerHTML = "Don't think about this";
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="changeText('hello','banana','wow','button1');" id="button1">

<button onclick="changeText('vewewve','vdsvs','dgsag','button2');" id="button2">
```

This code will set your text by default everytime you click on the button and language is not 3.

Comment: the snippet of course does not work because it only has the js part

Comment: I have 2 different buttons, which show 2 different texts when language == 3, but I want only text3 in the first button to have a different style. With that function text is green everytime language is 3

Comment: @Skalfaro i edited it adding a parameter that makes it happen